# HTML: Optimize way to display friends

Tags: xhtml, html

I want to create an optimized structure for following output in HTML.

[image: http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/5189/friendsdisplay.jpg]

rite now i m using this structure :

```
<div> 
    <div style="float:left; padding:5px;"> 
        <img src="avatar_url">
    </div> 
    <div style="float:left; padding:5px;">
        Name <br /> 
        Current Mood
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div align="right">
        Online Status
    </div>
</div>
```

but in some cases i have to display thousands of friends on one single page thats why i m trying to optimize the structure and remove unnecessary tags from the code.

Comment: Fewer tags won't necessarily yield faster rendering. You'll have to profile several layouts several times in several different browsers to see what reality has to say. I suspect that display several thousand of anything is going to be slow no matter what you do though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a bit simpler. Depending on how fancy you need to get, almost everything can be stripped away:

```
<div class="friend">
    <img ... />
    <hx>FULL NAME</hx>
    <p>Current Mood</p>
    <p class="status">Online Status</p>
</div>
```

The `hx` part is just a stand-in for whatever level of heading you would want to use for their name.

Here's some very minimal CSS to go with that:

```
.friend img { float:left; margin-right:5px; }
.status { text-align:right; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not paginate the results?

```
<div class="user">
  <img src="avatar.gif" class="user-avatar" />
  <h1 class="user-name">Name</h1>
  <h2 class="user-mood">Current mood.</h2>
  <div class="user-status">Online Status</div>
</div>
```

This is technically a few less tags however...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from removing the `div` around the avatar img (can you set the float/padding on the `img` element itself?), there isn't a lot you can do.

However, you can optimise the amount of text by creating a class for `float: left; padding: 5px` and using that class instead of the full style thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a lot there, but you surely can replace the style attribute with a class one

```
class="left"
```

with

```
.left { float:left;padding:5px; }
```

And you can also replace

```
<div class="clr"></div>
```

with

```
<div class="clr" />
```

Anyway, not much will change in the loading times.